# Whether ng2-nvD3 chart control will work on Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am now converting the angular core from 2.00 RC4 to 4.1
So, I want to know whether the ng2-nvD3 chart control will work on Angular 4 ?

Answer (score 3):

It does work, albeit a little unorthodoxly.

**How I got it to run in my Angular 4 project:**

Install as you would in an Angular 2 project:
`npm install ng2-nvd3`

Note: I have had to include a workaround, based on [this](https://github.com/krispo/ng2-nvd3/issues/33), to avoid the error `ReferenceError: nv is not defined`:

Inside `index.html` include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
```

There is almost certainly a better fix for this, but for the purpose of answering the "does it work" question, this is what I've done.

In you main module file (mine was `app/app.module.ts` based on the basic project created with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)) include the import and declare the directive:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import {nvD3} from 'ng2-nvd3';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    nvD3,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your component (mine was `app/app.component.ts`), specify the options and data functions (I used [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4i7Zh?p=preview) example):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

declare const d3: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'lineChart',
      height: 450,
      margin: {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 40,
        left: 55
      },
      x: function (d) {
        return d.x;
      },
      y: function (d) {
        return d.y;
      },
      useInteractiveGuideline: true,
      xAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Time (ms)'
      },
      yAxis: {
        axisLabel: 'Voltage (v)',
        tickFormat: function (d) {
          return d3.format('.02f')(d);
        },
        axisLabelDistance: -10
      }
    }
  };

  data: any = this.sinAndCos();


  sinAndCos() {
    const sin = [], sin2 = [], cos = [];

    // Data is represented as an array of {x,y} pairs.
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      sin.push({x: i, y: Math.sin(i / 10)});
      sin2.push({x: i, y: i % 10 === 5 ? null : Math.sin(i / 10) * 0.25 + 0.5});
      cos.push({x: i, y: .5 * Math.cos(i / 10 + 2) + Math.random() / 10});
    }

    // Line chart data should be sent as an array of series objects.
    return [
      {
        values: sin,      // values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
        key: 'Sine Wave', // key  - the name of the series.
        color: '#ff7f0e'  // color - optional: choose your own line color.
      },
      {
        values: cos,
        key: 'Cosine Wave',
        color: '#2ca02c'
      },
      {
        values: sin2,
        key: 'Another sine wave',
        color: '#7777ff',
        area: true      // area - set to true if you want this line to turn into a filled area chart.
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

And finally use it in your html (mine was `app/app.component.html`):

```
<div>
  <nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="data"></nvd3>
</div>
```

Best of luck. Please feel free to update with any better solutions as they become available :)